# Why do signs of association change in multilevel logistic regression?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, association-measure

In given data, the outcome of interest is a binary variable (who participated in the program? yes/no). Additionally, individuals are nested within districts that create correlated binary data. I've used simple logistic regression to assess the relationship between predictor and outcome. In addition, multilevel logistic regression (random intercept model) is considered due to clustered data to adjust the district level clustering. But I am getting two types of results for the same predictor (continuous variable within a range of 0-1) in two models; for example, 0.044 (simple model) and -0.077 (multilevel model). Why the signs of association is changing? Logically standard errors of estimates should be changed, not the signs. Can anybody give a description with reference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*One* possibility (out of many) is Simpson's paradox, e.g. https://hlplab.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/mixed-models-and-simpsons-paradox/

What do your data viz look like?

Comment: Many Thanks. Simpson's paradox also works similarly for mixed-effects logistic regression? I've just created a graph based on district (cluster) specific residuals, which shows substantial variation. Which types of visualisation will be good to understand this Simpson's paradox or others?